# jquery validation error while checking department name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have used the jquery validation for checking the department name is already exist in the specific organization. But its not returning the correct result. Please someone help me.

Here is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var validator = $("#frmAddDepartment").validate({
    errorElement:'div',
    rules: {
        organization:{
            required:true
        },
        department: {
            required: true,
            allowChars:true,
            //remote:$('#site_url').val()+"admin/department/check_department/"+$('#department').val()+"/"+$('#Organization').val(),
            checkdeptname:true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        organization:{
            required:languageArray['select_organization']
        },
        department:{
          required:languageArray['enter_department'],
          //remote:jQuery.format(languageArray['dept_exist'])
      }         
    }
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("allowChars", function(value, element) { 

    var filter = new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-& ]/);

        if(!(filter.test(value)))
        {
            return true;
        }else

            return false;
        },languageArray['please_enter_valid_chars']);

jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkdeptname", function(value, element) {  

    returnResult = false;

    $.ajax({
        url: $('#site_url').val()+"admin/department/check_department",
        type: "GET",
        data:{department:value,organization:$('#Organization').val()},
        success: function (result)
        {
            returnResult = result;
            alert(returnResult);
        }
    });
    //$.get( $('#site_url').val()+"admin/department/check_department", { department:value,organization:$('#Organization').val() }, function(data){alert(data);returnResult = result;} );
    return returnResult;
        },languageArray['dept_exist']);});
```

PHP controller's function:

```
public function check_department()
{
    $sql_query=$this->department_model->check_department();

    if($sql_query>0)
    {
        echo "false";
    }else
    {
        echo "true";
    }
}
```

Comment: allowFrenchChars is custom method?? and where it is defined?

Comment: its nice to post the correspoding error or result view for additional info

Comment: @user1978104 I have added the allowFrenchChar method. I have renamed it to allowChars. But thats not the issue. I am getting incorrect result while checking the department name via AJAX.

Comment: Use exit(); or die(); before closing of function. and return proper value from your php function .and get that value in ajax request.

Comment: @Roopendra Nothing is happening after adding exit code before the closing of the php function :(

Answer (score 0):

I think , in your php controller function you are returning ture/flase as String and on ajax success call back function your are comparing it with boolean ture/flase.

Comment: I added echo true instead of echo "true"; but still I am getting incorrect result.I am getting correct alert in success section but its not assigning the response to the returnResult variable.

Comment: Please suggest me any other solution. Since last 2 hours I am doing this.